# Create a calculated column from two different where statements in the same table using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

im trying to create a sql result which shows customers successrate(%) of their backupjobs.

i somehow want to combine the following queries to achive this:

```
select [colCustomerID],count(*) as Totalbackups FROM [BackupStat].[dbo].[tblJobSummary] group by [colCustomerID]

select [colCustomerID],count(*) as Failedbackups FROM [BackupStat].[dbo].[tblJobSummary] where [colStatus] !='Success' and [colStatus] !='Warning' group by [colCustomerID]
```

the result for the first query look something like this:

```
colCustomerID   Totalbackups
EXK-1670001 315
INK-2325001 8
INK-995001  5
INK-2326001 10
INK-1729001 7
INK-237001  2
GBG-3795001 4
INK-3422001 4
INK-3768001 138
INK-3780001 10
```

Comment: why don't you join the tables, and make the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 sub queries and then perform the calculation.  You will probably want to change the precision and scale in the decimal conversion.

EDIT: Added the Totalbackups column.

```
select 
    tb.colCustomerID,
    tb.Totalbackups,
    convert(decimal(5,2), fb.Failedbackups)/convert(decimal(5,2), tb.Totalbackups)
from    
(
    select 
        [colCustomerID],
        count(*) as Totalbackups 
    FROM [BackupStat].[dbo].[tblJobSummary] 
    group by [colCustomerID]
) tb
    inner join 
        (
            select 
                [colCustomerID],
                count(*) as Failedbackups 
            FROM [BackupStat].[dbo].[tblJobSummary] 
            where [colStatus] !='Success' 
                and [colStatus] !='Warning' 
            group by [colCustomerID]
        ) fb
            on tb.colCustomerID = fb.colCustomerID
```

Hope this helps!